# Is there some flag / pragma which can help me in detecting bogus variable names in a module definition?

Tags: verilog

[icarus verilog]

Is there some flag / pragma which can help me in detecting bogus variable names in a module definition?

Consider the following code fragment ...

```
module binary_decoder_2to4
(
    input wire enable,
    input wire[1:0] a,
    output wire[3:0] y
);

assign y[0] =  en & ~a[1] & ~a[0];
assign y[1] =  en & ~a[1] &  a[0];
assign y[2] =  en &  a[1] & ~a[0];
assign y[3] =  en &  a[1] &  a[0];

endmodule
```

As you can see I renamed port `en` to `enable` but I forgot to update the module body. Coming from a programming background I would expect the compiler (iverilog) to at least sound a warning. Instead the compiler happily generates a simulation file with the value of `en` set to `z`.

Comment: The one thing I know about verilog : "implicit none" is your friend.

Comment: What do I write to get "implicit none"?

Comment: Actually, this is a tool bug. Implicit nets are only _implicit_ when they appear in a port list or on the LHS of a continuous assignment. Here `en` appears on the RHS and should not become an implicit declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's actually a lot like the -W warning flags you're probably familiar with when using a C compiler like clang or gcc.

If you want to be extra careful, pass -Wall to iverilog.  This will turn on all warnings.  However, if you're just interested in the specific situation in your question, this is simply an implicit wire declaration.  You're using a wire named en, but since there is no 'en' wire in the module, where it is used is also where it is implicitly declared (which is certainly useful, but as you've discovered, can also obfuscate typos or simple human error). If you turn on the warning for this with -Wimplicit, iverilog will warn you about this.

There are other handy classes you may or may not want to use as well, and you can enable any combination of them by simply issuing several -W switches.  [Here](http://iverilog.wikia.com/wiki/Iverilog_Flags) is a good break down of the available options.

Hopefully this is what you wanted.  Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Verilog by default will treat any undeclared variable as a single bit wire. Since IEEE Std 1364-2001 (aka Verilog-2001) you can override the default with the `` `define_nettype `` macro. By setting it to `none` all nets must be explicitly declared. This is a universal solution that works on all modern simulators; the base line is IEEE Std 1364-2001 compliance.

Add the line `` `default_nettype none `` to the top of the first file being compiled and the rule will apply to all files. If you want some modules to have explicitly declaration and others to allow implicit, then for all modules needing explicitly declaration have `` `default_nettype none `` above and `` `default_nettype wire `` below those modules.

You can get more details on default_nettype by reading IEEE Std 1364-2001 § 19.2 *`default_nettype* or [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 22.8 *`default_nettype*